# How can I retrieve the types.Object for a types.Type

Tags: go, types

I am using `golang.org/x/tools/go/packages` to load a Go package and inspect a struct. I want to know the `packages.Package` from which the struct fields are imported.

```
func load() (any, error) {
    pkg, err := loadPackage(".")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    st, err := loadStruct(pkg, "myStruct")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for i := 0; i < st.NumFields(); i++ {
        field := st.Field(i)

        // Let's say this field is like `amount decimal.Decimal` how can I get
        // a reference to the decimal package as a packages.Package
        // FIXME
    }

    return nil, nil
}

func loadPackage(name string) (*packages.Package, error) {
    pkgs, err := packages.Load(
        &packages.Config{
            Mode: packages.NeedName | packages.NeedImports | packages.NeedDeps |
                packages.NeedTypes | packages.NeedTypesInfo | packages.NeedSyntax}, ".")
    if err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Fatal("failed to load package")
    }
    if len(pkgs) != 1 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("expected 1 package, got %d", len(pkgs))
    }
    return pkgs[0], nil
}

func loadStruct(pkg *packages.Package, name string) (*types.Struct, error) {
    obj := pkg.Types.Scope().Lookup(name)
    if obj == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not find struct %s", name)
    }
    st, ok := obj.Type().Underlying().(*types.Struct)
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%s is not a struct", name)
    }
    return st, nil
}
```

Comment: Get `field.Type()`, then resolve that to `*types.Named`, then use [`Obj`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/types@go1.20#Named.Obj) to get the `types.TypeName` which has a `Pkg()` method that returns a `*types.Package`. Use its [`Path`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/types@go1.20#Package.Path) to lookup the `package.Package` in the `pkgs` slice returned by `packages.Load`.

Comment: When I do this my type isn't a `*types.Named`? It is a `*types.Struct`

Comment: Ah wait I was using `f.Type().Underlying()`, it works with just `f.Type()`

Comment: Keep in mind that you may need to handle things like pointers, slices, or other composites, e.g. `amount *decimal.Decimal`/`amount []decimal.Decimal`. Such fields will of course not return `types.Named` but rather `types.Pointer`/`types.Slice`, so you'll need to "dig deeper" to get the named type.